# sort / filter gallery 'see all' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a sort filter on a gallery of divs that contain images and captions.

This seemed to be working before but now the first button (ver todos — show all) is not working. All the others work.

I think Flexbox is conflicting with my JS?
I just can’t figure out how to make it work. I am a beginner in JS, so please be thorough in your reasoning in this regard.

Any help is appreciated!

HTML:

```
<section class="catalog">
    <div id="buttons">
    </div>
    <div id="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-item cadeiras" data-tags="cadeiras">
                <div class="item_views">
                    <img src="images/C642_A.jpg" alt="cadeira de despacho" />
                    <p class="legendas">Cadeirão de orelhas<br />Mogno entalhado <br />Trabalho do fim do Séc. XIX, estofo posterior</p>
                </div>
                <div class="item_views">
                    <img src="images/C642_B.jpg" width="296" height="342" alt="cadeira de despacho" />
                    <p class="legendas legendas_en">Armchair<br />Carved mahogany<br />Late 19th century <span class="legenda_notas">(reupholstered)</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-item cadeiras" data-tags="cadeiras">
                <div class="item_views">
                    <img src="images/C608_A.jpg" alt="cadeirão de orelhas" />
                    <p class="legendas">Cadeira de despacho<br />Pau santo entalhado<br />Portugal, meados do Séc. XVIII</p>
                </div>
                <div class="item_views">
                    <img src="images/C608_B.jpg" alt="cadeirão de orelhas" />
                    <p class="legendas legendas_en">Bureau armchair<br />Carved rosewood<br />Portugal, mid-18th century</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="gallery-item cadeiras bancos" data-tags="bancos">
            <div class="item_views">
                <img src="images/C249_A.jpg" alt="tamborete" />
                <p class="legendas">Tamborete<br />Nogueira entalhada<br />Portugal, Séc. XVIII</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item_views">
                <img src="images/C249_B.jpg" alt="tamborete" />
                <p class="legendas legendas_en">A stool<br />Carved walnut<br />Portugal, 18th century</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-item bancos" data-tags="bancos">
            <div class="item_views">
                <img src="images/C508.jpg" alt="banco sec XIX" />
                <p class="legendas">Banco<br />Madeira, ferro e sola, feito à maneira do sec. XVII<br />Dimensões: 1,40 x 0,.43 x 0,93 m. (A.)<br />Portugal, Séc. XIX</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item_views">
                <p class="legendas legendas_en">Bench<br />Wood, leather and iron, manufactured in the way of the 17th century<br />1,40  m. long<br />Portugal, 19th century</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="gallery-item mesas indo-port" data-tags="mesas, indo-português">
            <div class="item_views">
                <img src="images/mesa_ip1.jpg" alt="mesa" />
                <p class="legendas">Mesa de centro Indo-Portuguesa<br />Teca com embutidos e guarnições em ébano. Fecharias e pingentes de ferro forjado.<br />Caixa com 8 gavetas moldadas e 4 aparentes. Pés entalhados com forma de sereias (Naguinis) e travessas decoradas com enrolamentos.<br /> Dimensões: 1,30 (C.) x 0,97 (L.) x 0,85 (A.) m.<br />Séc. XVII</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item_views">
                <img src="images/mesa_ip2.jpg" alt="mesa" />
                <p class="legendas legendas_en">Indo-Portuguese hall table<br />Teak with ebony inlay, cast iron mounts<br />With 8 drawers and 4 aparent drawers. Legs carved in the shape of mermaids (naginis).<br />1,30 (long) x 0,97 (deep) x 0,85 (tall) m. <br />17th century</p><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="gallery-item mesas indo-port" data-tags="mesas, indo-português">
        <div class="item_views">
            <img src="images/C444_A.jpg" alt="mesa indo-portuguesa" />
            <p class="legendas">Mesa Indo-Portuguesa<br /> Teca, sissó e marfim, com ferragens de metal serrado<br />Dimensões: 90 (L.) x 58 (P.) x 77 (A.) cm<br />Trabalho do Séc. XVII</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item_views">
            <img src="images/C444_B.jpg" alt="tampo da mesa" />
            <p class="legendas legendas_en">Indo-Portuguese table<br />Teak, sisoo and ivory. Pierced metal mounts.<br />90 cm.  x 58 cm. x 77 cm. high <br />17th century</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  var $items = $('div.gallery-item');
  var $buttons = $('#buttons');
  var tagged = {};

  $items.each(function() {
    var thisDiv = this;
    var tags = $(this).data('tags');

    if (tags) {
      tags.split(',').forEach(function(tagName) {
        if (tagged[tagName] == null) {
          tagged[tagName] = [];
        }
        tagged[tagName].push(thisDiv);
      });
    }
  });

  $('<button/>', {
    text: 'ver todos',
    class: 'active',
    click: function() {
      $(this)
        .addClass('active')
        .sibblings()
        .removeClass('active');
      $items.show();
    },
  }).appendTo($buttons);

  $.each(tagged, function(tagName) {
    $('<button/>', {
      text: tagName,
      click: function() {
        $(this)
          .addClass('active')
          .siblings()
          .removeClass('active');
        $items
          .hide()
          .filter(tagged[tagName])
          .show();
      },
    }).appendTo($buttons);
  });
})();

CSS

#gallery {
  margin-top:2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.gallery-item {
  width: 950px;
  display: flex;
  margin:0 2.5em 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.item_views {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: .2em;
  justify-content: flex-end; /*v-align to bottom */
  background-image: url(../images/bg4.gif);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
.gallery-item > .item_views:nth-child(2) {
  align-items: flex-start;
}
button {
    color: #7e7e9c;
    font-family: "motiva-sans",sans-serif;
    font-size: .9em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    margin: 0 9px 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: solid thin #c8cdd5;
    transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
button:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 #7e7e9c;
}
button.active {
  color: #000;
  border: solid 2px #000;
}
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 #000;
  transform: scale(0.99);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got a typo in your "ver todos" button declaration: it calls `.sibblings()` instead of `.siblings()`. Does it work when you fix this?

(If you open your browser's developer tools while this code is running and watch the console, you should see an error like `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addClass(...).sibblings is not a function`, which helps to find the problem in your code.)

Comment: You are absolutely right.
I totally missed that in the console!
100% working now, thank you so much for your help.